# compare two columns in two different sheets

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

i would like to compare two columns in two different sheets like column A in sheet 1 start from row 2 till the last row and columns C start from row 2 till the last row. If row in column A is greater than the same row in column C a message box " the value is greater" appear and clear the greater value in column A. Thanks an advance for your support

Comment: This can be done using pure excel formulas. See the IF-Function for details. You might end up with sheet 3 holding one column with the comparison result and may be two further colums with data or blank cells depending on the comparison column.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started

```
Sub compare()

Dim sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim sheet2 As Worksheet
Set sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = sheet1.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To lastrow

    If sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value > sheet2.Range("A" & i).Value Then

        MsgBox ("the value is greater")
        sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value = ""

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Delete Greater Than

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub deleteGreaterThan()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim dst As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set dst = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set src = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    LastRow = dst.Cells(dst.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If dst.Cells(i, "A").Value > src.Cells(i, "C").Value Then
            MsgBox "The value in cell '" & dst.Cells(i, "A").Address(0, 0) _
              & "' is greater."
            dst.Cells(i, "A").Value = ""
        End If
    
    Next i

End Sub
```